# Can't build OpenCV with dynamic library

Tags: opencv, cmake

I want to build OpenCV 4.6.0 with dynamic library, while even I checked BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=1, the install folder only contains
[these files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K8ci.png)

I expect there would be many dll files so that I can copy those files to Unity for me to use opencv_with_cuda in Unity.

Here is my build setting in CMake:

```
Commandline options:
-DCUDA_ARCH_BIN:STRING="6.1" -DCUDA_FAST_MATH:BOOL="1" -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH:PATH="C:/opencv_version_4.6.0/opencv_contrib-4.6.0/modules" -DENABLE_FAST_MATH:BOOL="1" -DWITH_CUDA:BOOL="1" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL="1" -DBUILD_opencv_world:BOOL="1" -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES:STRING="Release" -DOPENCV_DNN_CUDA:BOOL="1" 


Cache file:
CUDA_ARCH_BIN:STRING=6.1
CUDA_FAST_MATH:BOOL=1
OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH:PATH=C:/opencv_version_4.6.0/opencv_contrib-4.6.0/modules
ENABLE_FAST_MATH:BOOL=1
WITH_CUDA:BOOL=1
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=1
BUILD_opencv_world:BOOL=1
CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES:STRING=Release
OPENCV_DNN_CUDA:BOOL=1
```

Except the Python2 warning, I only encounter this warning:

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 (message):
  CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install
  directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1039 (include)
```

The whole configuration is like t

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.6.0 =====================================   Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            C:/opencv_version_4.6.0/opencv_contrib-4.6.0/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2022-09-12T09:13:27Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.19044 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.24.1
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 16 2019
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1929
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (18 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (33 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (8 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe (ver 19.29.30146.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /MP   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /MP /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO 
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          cudart_static.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib cudnn.lib cufft.lib
-LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.6/lib/x64
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco barcode bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab wechat_qrcode world xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    -
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 alphamat cvv freetype java julia matlab ovis python2 python2 sfm viz
    Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.12)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.2-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   C:/opencv_version_4.6.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                C:/opencv_version_4.6.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.6, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             61
    NVIDIA PTX archs:

  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.4.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/opencv_version_4.6.0/opencv-4.6.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Users/turtl/anaconda3/python.exe (ver 3.9.12)
    Libraries:                   C:/Users/turtl/anaconda3/libs/python39.lib (ver 3.9.12)
    numpy:                       C:/Users/turtl/anaconda3/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver
1.21.5)
    install path:                C:/Users/turtl/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cv2/python-3.9

  Python (for build):            C:/Users/turtl/anaconda3/python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/opencv_version_4.6.0/build/install
```

One thing to note, no error during building while this warning comes out frequently, doesn't know if this relates to not building dynamic library
warning : field of class type without a DLL interface used in a class with a DLL interface.